# Let's populate our help section!

Tags: discussion

I think we should have a (semi)-complete help section by the time we get out of private beta. Therefore, I thing we should start making our help section *right now*. Each answer to this question is a CW answer, so feel free to edit whatever you can to populate various sections of the help. I have selected the main sections of our [help](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) that we should probably modify for our uses. Let's do this!

Comment: The only sections that can be customized per site are the “Ask about…” and “Don't ask about …” boxes on the [tour page](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and the text on [“What topics can I ask about here?”](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Yes, what @Gilles said. You can only edit that one section (I removed the others you linked). But please don't get overenthusiastic about adding a bunch of rules and scope restrictions to that section until you actually run into wide-spread problems in actual practice. That's not the way to build a friendly, welcoming community.

Comment: Ok. Is off-topic editable too?

Comment: @TheDoctor No, only /help/on-topic. As a result, most sites put their do-not-ask list there. See [scifi's](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

### [What topics can I ask about here?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Puzzling Stack Exchange is for people studying the creation and solving of puzzles.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puzzle) defines **puzzle** as a game or problem which tests the ingenuity of a would-be solver. In a puzzle, one is required to put pieces together, in a logical way, in order to arrive at the correct solution of the puzzle. There are different types of puzzles:

- A chess problems
- Jigsaw puzzles
- Mathematical puzzles
- Mechanical puzzles
- Metapuzzles, puzzles which unite elements of other puzzles.
- Paper-and-pencil puzzles
- Peg solitaire
- Sangaku
- Sliding puzzles
- Sokoban
- Spot the Difference
- Tangram
- Word puzzles, including anagrams, ciphers, crossword puzzles, and word search puzzles.

**We welcome questions about**:

- Creation of puzzles. For example:

  - "How to make this puzzle more difficult?".
- Solution or strategy for a specific puzzle or puzzle group. For example:

  - "How to solve this puzzle?"
  - "Why this solution works?"
  - "General strategy for [2048](http://git.io/2048)"
- A facts about a specific puzzle. For example:

  - "Who is the author of this puzzle?"
  - "How many distinct unsolvable Rubik's cubes exist?"
- The rules of a specific puzzle