# Where is the definition of an on-topic question?

Tags: discussion

I expected to find it here https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic but that page only suggests searching to see if your question has been asked before.

Is there a page a definition of questions considered on-topic for Puzzling Stack Exchange?

Comment: There is a discussion of what is on-topic here : http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3142/list-examples-of-things-you-think-are-on-topic-or-off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there is, and that page is it!--but it hasn't been filled in yet.

**That page can be edited** with discussion on Meta, but so far **nobody's actually suggested anything to put there.** Feel free to ask a question about what should go there!

(While there have been [a couple before](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1312/what-should-our-help-center-say-about-on-topic-questions), they were [from a long, long time ago](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27/lets-populate-our-help-section/28), so it might be better to start a new discussion.)