# The on-topic page in the Help Centre

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Recently, I needed to check whether or not a question was considered on-topic or not for this site, so naturally I went to check [the on-topic section of the help centre](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and to my surprise found that all it showed was this:

> **What topics can I ask about here?**
>
> Please [look around](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search) to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/self-answer).
>
> If your question is not specifically on-topic for Puzzling Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or [propose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

I think it's about time we edited this page to contain a better definition of what is considered on-topic for this site. I've found a few discussions ([1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27/lets-populate-our-help-section/28), [2](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1312/what-should-our-help-center-say-about-on-topic-questions))  on here about this, but they are from a long time ago, and didn't really go anywhere.

I propose we replace the page with the following:

---

## What topics can I ask about here?

**Puzzling Stack Exchange** is for puzzle-makers and puzzle enthusiasts of all levels. If you have a question about:

- Creating or improving puzzles
- A specific method of solving a type of puzzle
- A well-known (perhaps unsolved) puzzle

Then this site is the right place for you! Here at Puzzling Stack Exchange, we welcome puzzles to be posted as question as well. The following guidelines should help you post a good puzzle:

- If you are not the author of the puzzle, it is a good idea to reference the original author or source where you found the puzzle.
- Puzzles must not be from active competitions. If a puzzle is from an active competition, it will be locked until after the competition has ended.
- If you do not have the solution to the puzzle, state so in the question.
- For puzzles where the solution is known, the solution must be unique and stand out from any other possible solution.
- If your puzzle is a real unsolved puzzle, tag it with [unsolved-mysteries](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unsolved-mysteries).

Most types of puzzles are on-topic here, you can read specific guidelines for puzzle types [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3142/list-examples-of-things-you-think-are-on-topic-or-off-topic), or through looking at the relevant tag descriptions.

---

Before posting a puzzle, you might want to read about [what makes a good question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1650/challenge-questions-and-post-quality-how-should-we-proceed/1651#1651) and [the features of a good puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5880/what-are-the-features-of-a-well-written-puzzle). If you are still unsure whether or not your question is on-topic for this site, feel free to ask on [our meta site](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/), or to browse through previous discussions there on what is considered on-topic.

Please [look around](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search) to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/self-answer).

If your question is not specifically on-topic for Puzzling Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or [propose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for this! This is a real great draft. I've made a few small edits to it and updated the Help Center with almost entirely your copy. [It's now live!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Feel free to ping me or another moderator with a comment or in chat if there are typos or if other edits for clarity etc. should be made, or if there's glaringly incorrect or obviously missing information.